# how to run .slx file using .m script

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have an .slx file at location:
C:\M1\M2\M3\chart.slx

and a .m file at location:
C:\M1\M2\M3\mfile.m

I want to run this .slx file with MATLAB, not from command window, from a script or the editor in MATLAB. How can I do this? Is this possible?

Comment: just `sim('chart')` - but the model does not open for that, you would need `open('chart')` additionally.

Comment: More info at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/sim.html